# Lumen Auth:attempt() will not persist login

Tags: laravel, lumen

I have installed fresh copy of lumen v5.6 and write new microservice of user login. But when I enter my login detail and use

```
Auth::attempt($credential)
```

method for login then I recive following error all then time

```
Method Illuminate\\Auth\\RequestGuard::attempt does not exist
```

Below is my working method

```
public static function loginUser($credentials) {
   if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
       echo "<pre>";
       print_r('ok');
       exit;   
   }
   return [];      
}
```

Below is my user model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Laravel\Lumen\Auth\Authorizable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;

class User extends BaseModel implements AuthenticatableContract, AuthorizableContract {

    use Authenticatable,
        Authorizable;

    /**
     * modal table
     * @var type
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * modal primary key
     * @var type
     */
    protected $primarykey = 'id';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['full_name', 'username', 
           'email','password',  'picture'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [];


    public static function saveNewUser($inputs) {
        $user = new User($inputs);
        if ($user->save()) {
            return $user;
        }
        return [];
    }


    /**
     * login user
     * @param type $credentials
     * @return type
     */
    public static function loginUser($credentials) {
        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r('ok');
            exit;   
        }
        return [];      
    }

}
```

I don't know that whats the issue. I implement the auth configuration method too but failed to resolve this issue. Now I am stuck on user login process. Guide in right direction and provide any usefull link to solve this issue.

Comment: The doc says: Before using Lumen's authentication features, you should uncomment the call to register the `AuthServiceProvider` service provider in your `bootstrap/app.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

Add this middleware to your route :

```
Route::get('/users/{user}', 'UserController@show')->middleware('auth:api');
```